# How to use ObjectDataProvider at design time?

Tags: wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider

I am using an ObjectDataProvider declared in the XAML as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpTheList" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type library:StaticClass}"
                        MethodName="GetListOfItems" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Basically it calls `StaticClass.GetListOfItems()` to get the data.

Ok, the problem is that this GetListOfItems throws an exception when i am in design time - it actually gets the data from the database; 
The problem is the designer crashes (understandably), but is there a way to use the ObjectDataProvider like i am trying to use and still have the designer support?..

At runtime, it works perfectly.

I also tried to set `IsInitialLoadEnabled="False"`, but without success.

Thanx in advance.